# SAN Replication for Fault tolerance using EVA4400

Tags: replication, vmware-esx, storage-area-network

I hope that someone would point me in the correct direction - it looks like I have no enough konwledge in the subject and timeframes are too tight for me to explore different scenarios in depth..

We have two datacenters few miles away from each other connected by 100 Mbps link.Each datacenter will have 5 BL490 blades with ESX Standard hosting about 50 VMs. Eac hsite has HP eva4400 SAN with SAN replication set up.VC is going to be in the first datacenter and both datacenter are networked.

SAN Replication is block level so it seems like I cannot just replicate changes but all writes would have to be replicated.This should not be a problem as link can sustain about 1.8 TB a dayand data can be buffered.

I am having trouble however visioning how recovery would work in this case.We don't need instant recovery , I would say 4 hours recovery time is accepted so fancy automatic SRM like DR scenario would not be easily accepted due to the financial reasons, however any comments are welcomed.

Current idea is following: replicate LUNs from primary site to the secondary.When disaster strikes, IT personnel switches on ESX hosts on the remote side and connects replicated LUNS to them, then registers VMs and changes IP address.

I understand that this seems like horribly manual process and I almost sure I have missed some obvious pitfalls here.

Could someone let me know what direction should I go?An articles regarding the subject?

This is a brand new setup and we would rather build up basic recovery process and scale it later.I just need to have a right direction to allow for such scalability.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sergei,

We do something similar with two EVA 8000 except ours are within a half mile of each other and connected by fibre.
If you have hot spare ESX servers then each time you create a new source LUN on the EVA present them also also to the spare ESX servers. They will have no read write access by default until failed over.
 Each time you do this or at least once in a while you need to rescan the HBA in the ESX servers to pick new LUNS.
In disaster all you need to do is fail over the LUNs and reregister the VM's.
Don't see why you would need to change IP adresses. surely only one set will on at any time.
Also if you can test once in while and register the VM's then that step is removed also.

The whole process can be done in minutes not hours.

Answer (score 1):

Sergei,

We are currently doing a similar design at work. Although not HP SAN's take a look at [this site](http://www.vmware.com/technical-resources/virtual-storage/basics.html). You may need to invest in VCenter (formerly Virtual Center) where you can register the hosts and do a HA for VMs. As your replication is block level, the VMs can share the storage clusters for redundancy.